# Strange behaviour of ParseQuery

Tags: android, parse-platform

Code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Order");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject object : list) {

                }
            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

found ParseObjects only created by current ParseUser.

It's normal behavior?

Comment: Yes thats normal..For the installation and the user object you should be getting the current user information if you havent added the query information

Comment: But i want to found all of "Order" objects in db, not only created by one user.

In my opinion, right behavior of "query.findInBackground" is:

1. By default found all objects

2. If add condition "query.whereEqualTo("owner", currentUser)" found objects, created by current user.